# assistance required with complex integrals please

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm a bit stuck on a question on complex integrals I have no idea how to go about solving it and would be really grateful if someone could help.

The question is: 2. Let

$$\  F(x,y,z)=(2xy+4xz)i+(x^2+6yz)j+(2x^2+3y^2)k,x,y,z∈R. $$
(a) Find a function $\ ϕ:R^3→R $ 
such that  $\ \vec F⃗ = \nabla ϕ. $

(d) Evaluate the integral  $$\ \int_Γ(\vec F .\vec {dr} ) $$

where Γ is the path
$\ y=x^2,z=0 $
from (0,0,0) to (2,4,0) followed by the line segment from 
(2,4,0) to (1,1,2)

Comment: Have you had any practice with computing line integrals before?

Comment: Hi @user170231 thanks for getting back to me. I haven't a lot no I've just started so any help would be hugely appreciated. I have no clue what to do for part a but im thinking that for part d I would parameterize?

Comment: I have to be away from my computer at the moment, but for now try taking a look at [this worked example](http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_find_potential_3d) which should cover all the details you need. Part (a) involves computing $\nabla\times\vec{F}$ to find the potential function $\phi$. You could compute the integral by parameterizing the contour, but I suspect the solution to part (a) would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks so much! @user170231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the potential function $\phi$, we need only integrate the components of $\vec F$.  To proceed, we begin with the $\hat x$-component to find

$$\begin{align}
\phi(x,y,z)&=\int F_x(x,y,z)\,dx\\\\
&=\int (2xy+4xz)\,dx\\\\
&=x^2y+2x^2z+C_1(y,z) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $C_1(y,z)$ is an integration constant with respect to $x$, but can depend on both $y$ and $z$.

Next, we use $\phi(x,y)$ as given in $(1)$ to find $C_1(y,z)$.  Noting that $\frac{\partial \phi(x,y,z)}{\partial y}=F_y(x,y,z)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
x^2+\frac{\partial C_1(,y,z)}{\partial y}=x^2+6yz
\end{align}$$

from which we find $C_1(y,z)=3y^2z+C_2(z)$, where $C_2(z)$ is a second integration constant.  At this point, we can write the potential function as

$$\phi(x,y,z)=x^2y+2x^2z+3y^2z+C_2(z) \tag 2$$

Finally, taking the partial of $\phi(x,y,z)$, as given by $(2)$, with respect to $z$, and setting it equal to $F_z(x,y,z)$ yields

$$2x^2+3y^2+C_2'(z)=2x^2+3y^2$$

from which we find that $C_2(z)$ is a constant.

Therefore, we can write the potential function as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\phi(x,y,z)=x^2y+2x^2z+3y^2z+C}$$

for any constant $C$.

---

Since we have determined that $\vec F(x,y,z)\nabla \phi(x,y,z)$, $\vec F$ is conservative, and its path integral depends only on the end points of the path.  We can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r_2}\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot \vec d\vec \ell&=\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r_2} \nabla \phi(x,y,z)\cdot d\vec \ell\\\\
&=\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r_2} d\phi\\\\
&=\phi(1,1,2)-\phi(0,0,0)\\\\
&=11\end{align}$$

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark